# Matlab Matrix Dimensonality

Tags: matlab

I am trying to solve a problem numerically via element wise through a loop. When I hard code a value for the index number "i=3" for example, the equations are solved and everything works but when I try to run the loop for all index values (i=1,2,3,...), I get a matrix dimensionality problem. Very unusual. What am I doing wrong? I appreciate your help.

```
alpha=.4
beta=.9
delta=.3
sigma=.8

k=0:10
coeff=[.99 .6]
%fun=[k(i)^alpha+(1-delta)*k(i)-c (k(i)^alpha+(1-delta)*k(i)-c)^2]
con=zeros(length(k),1)

for i=1:length(k)
syms c
fun=[k(i)^alpha+(1-delta)*k(i)-c (k(i)^alpha+(1-delta)*k(i)-c)^2]
con(i)=vpasolve(c^(-sigma)-beta*((dot(coeff,fun))^(-sigma))*(1+alpha*(k(i)+(1-delta)*k(i)-c)-delta)==0,c,[0,100])

end
```

If you run:

```
    i=3
    fun=[k(i)^alpha+(1-delta)*k(i)-c (k(i)^alpha+(1-delta)*k(i)-c)^2]
    con(i)=vpasolve(c^(-sigma)-beta*((dot(coeff,fun))^(-sigma))*(1+alpha*(k(i)+(1-delta)*k(i)-c)-delta)==0,c,[0,100])
```

You don't get a dimensionality error.

```
Improper assignment with rectangular empty    matrix.
```

Comment: when the loop runs for the first time then `k(1)=0` for which you get a `0x1 sym matrix` which is also hinted by the error message. What do you think what answer you should be getting for `k=0`. It seems that  you would like to use `k=1:10` instead of `k=0:10`.

Comment: There are just 10 loop iteration: try to manually unroll the loop and try to see where you get the error: I agree with the observation of @Sardar_Usama